# Is there a performance hit for querying two different databases?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, A and B, which are located in different databases on the same MySQL server.  I would like to create a derived table C from tables A and B, as an inner join between the two tables.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
create table C as select A.gene, B.pubmed_id, B.pubmed_text from A inner join B ...
```

Will there be a performance hit in doing so? Would it be more prudent to load tables A and B into the same database? These are both very big tables with millions of records.

Comment: Where are you going to create 'C' . Along with 'A' or with 'B'. Or any 3rd database. Off course, A and B in same database will boost performance as database selection will be one shot.

Comment: I'll create C in the same database as table A. Only table B is in a different database.

Comment: And what is the impediment you are facing to create table B in the same database where table A resides ?

Comment: We wanted table B to be in a different database, because our application doesn't use it (it's a dependency for some derived tables).

Answer (score 3):

There is essentially no difference between `table` and `db.table`.  Once the tables (for SELECT or for INSERT) is opened, it is just a table, regardless of what database it is in.